# Fniding consecutive sequences with a given filter width in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pattern-matching, sequence, gaps-and-islands

I was using MYSQL for storing signals which are sampled for a given period. My task involves identifying the faulty signal based on a filter width. The signal table consists of the signal index along with its value. During primary filtering, I was able to get the index of the sequence where there is a mismatch. The filtered table now consists of indexes of the signal where there is a mismatch. Now, I want to count the number of instances when the signal is faulty.

For examples, the filtered table consists of indexes like `3,4,5,6,9,10,13,16`, if I apply a filter of width 3 then there are two instance where the signal is faulty as indicated by the index sequence `3,4,5` and `4,5,6`. If I apply a filter of width 2 then similarly there are 4 instances.

I want to count this by using sql queries on the table which consists of these indexes.
For now this is what I'm doing for a filter width of 2.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_index AS t1 INNER JOIN table_index AS t2 WHERE t1.id+1=t2.id;
```

But this approach is quite costly, when applying a filter width of 3 and more as one need to use inner join on those many tables.
Is there any efficient way of doing this using SQL queries only? Or do I need to do these analysis by reading these indexes in another way? (Ex: using python)

Thank you.

Comment: Your first paragraph talks about signals.  The second introduces something called an "index".  That is actually a very important concept in databases.  I don't understand what it means in terms of your data.

Comment: My question is little confused as you mention. I edited my question to include what I call as "index". It is basically an index referring to a row where the value is not correct. And as the values themselves are not meaningful, I was doing analysis on the indexes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id as starting_id
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON t1.id BETWEEN t2.id - @filter_count + 1 AND t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = @filter_count;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f91a3afd445b8c37c4439a8720d97c1d)

Comment: I don't understand how this 'scales'!?!

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry english is not my native... I cannot understand your phrase.

Comment: This approach seems to be good, but in actual for my data, its taking forever to run. I'm trying out some different approach, I'll let you know when I finish that.

Comment: @naveennamani 1) Specify your MySQL version. 2) Specify the table structure, including indexes, and the method which is used for filtering.